# What's this JSON format when generically connecting to Mifi/Jetpack GPS over Wi-Fi (NMEA)?

Tags: nmea, linux-mint

I just bought a Mifi 4G wifi modem, which Verizon, a US mobile company, has rebranded as a 'Jetpack'.

While playing with the settings, I found that it also has a GPS receiver built into it, and offers what it calls 'GPS over Wi-Fi (NMEA)'. It comes with a driver for connecting to Windows' GPS system, but no drivers for other operating systems. An extensive session of websearching has not found any Linux tools for connecting to this device, nor any information about connecting `gpsd`, the Linux GPS daemon, to an NMEA source via wifi.

But I've done a bit of hacking and have found that I can curl the current GPS data in JSON format:

```
$ curl http://192.168.1.1/gps/status/
{"gBaseAssetsPath":"09101217","gHtmlLang":"en-US","gIsLoggedIn":1,"gLangDirection":"ltr","gLocale":"en_US","gPageId":"gps_status","gSecureToken":"0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567","gpsIsOff":0,"gpsPrivacyCheckbox":1,"gpsStartupState":0,"gpsStatus":2,"gpsStatusAltitude":"1733 m","gpsStatusHeading":0,"gpsStatusLatitude":37.76520123,"gpsStatusLongitude":-112.24160123,"gpsStatusSatelliteCount":0,"gpsStatusTimestamp":435803696,"gpsStatusUncertainty":"10 m","haveInternet":1}
```

That's certainly good enough for me to write code to interpret it, but it'd be nice if I could get `gpsd` to connect to it as well, so I can use other Linux GPS tools.

Is 'GPS over Wi-Fi (NMEA)' a rebranded name for some protocol that I could websearch for?

I'm far from an expert, but that JSON format doesn't look remotely like NMEA, but maybe it's some other standard format, and I could websearch for that.

Any Linux advice about piping lat/long into `gpsd` so it's available to other apps would be welcome too, of course.

Comment: Looks like not-NMEA. Possibly there is mode setting that can kick the format, or another endpoint, or maybe an option on that endpoint.

Comment: See https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/997737/using-novatel-gps-usb-driver-on-jetson-tx1-developer-kit/ there's a Novatel (MiFi manufacturer) linux gps usb driver.

Comment: https://www.novatel.com/support/info/documents/809